# Groovy - for loops in mutli-line strings?

Tags: groovy

How can I loop through a list of values, including each one into a Groovy multi-line string?

#### Example

```
myList = ['one', 'two', 'three']
myString = """
           some text
           ${for(item in myList){item}}
           some more text
           """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List.join`

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    def myList = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    def myString = """
       some text
       ${myList.join()}
       some more text
       """
    println myString
}
```